# How to Access third Party API (Like as: Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter) using Spring ROO

Tags: spring-roo, spring-social

I am trying to Access third party API like as: Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter using Spring ROO. Is it possible to do using Spring ROO? If it is possible, Please help me, how can i do this.

Thanks
Muni

Answer (score 2):

If you are specifically targeting social networks integration, you can easily integrate [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) to your Spring Roo project.

If you are looking more into third party API Integration, you can use [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) within your Spring Roo project.

Add the Spring Social or Spring Integration as a dependency to your projects `pom.xml` and you are ready to go.

Cheers!!!