# How to integrate facebook graph api in Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

I am very new to Spring Roo. I have decided to create my first project in Spring Roo that should implement facebook graph api. I have found few api (fbRest, facebook-api-java) after searching over the internet but some blogs say these are old. I don't know, where i get appropriate api that is supported by spring roo and how to start? Any help be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply integrate Spring Social add-on to add Social features to your Spring Roo project, just like you would do for any Java project. :)

Please see the following answer for a similar question.

[How to Access third Party API (Like as: Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter) using Spring ROO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907528/how-to-access-third-party-api-like-as-facebook-linkedin-twitter-using-spring/6908114#6908114)