# How to integrate spring social in Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

What's the simple procedures (step-by-step) to integrate Spring Social in Spring Roo? I am currently using STS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see the following similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553189/how-to-integrate-facebook-graph-api-in-spring-roo/7554259#7554259

Comment: Is there any add-ons in spring roo that can be used for Spring social?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any add-ons in spring roo that can be used for Spring social?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571427/is-there-any-add-ons-in-spring-roo-that-can-be-used-for-spring-social)