# Is there any add-ons in spring roo that can be used for Spring social?

Tags: spring-roo

Is there any add-ons in spring roo that can be used for Spring social? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now, there doesn't seem to be any.

Please see the following discussion on the SpringSource forums.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111418-Add-on-for-spring-social-in-spring-roo